# Get User's Group policy settings

Tags: c#, group-policy

I am trying to get logged in user's group policy settings to map their server shared folders in web site. i tried using Microsoft.GroupPolicy and System.DirectoryServices but they are not working for me or I am doing something wrong.
User login to website with AD confirmation and password confirmation from sql so dual check. then I need to get group policy settings to get drive mapping for that user so i can show them their mapped drives on the website. is there anyway to accomplish that?

I have tried

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;


GPRsop rsop = new GPRsop(RsopMode.Logging, "root\\RSOP\\Computer");
rsop.LoggingComputer = "MyComputer";
rsop.LoggingUser = "domain\\user";
rsop.LoggingMode = LoggingMode.Computer;
rsop.CreateQueryResults();
rsop.GenerateReportToFile(ReportType.Xml, "C:\\Temp\\test.xml");
```

Comment: Are you trying to get users access to a SQL Server Database?  The database owns the mdf file that is used for the database.  Users do not have access to the mdf.  So users should connect to the server (not attach the mdf file in connection string).  To give users access to the database have the database use a Window Credential and make the credential a Windows User Group Account (or a group policy).  Then all users that belong to the group will have access.

Comment: I need to get network shared folder paths from group policy features for each login user and show their folders on web site. When they login to work computers group policy automatically load shared folder paths which they are allow to see on computer. I want to show them when they are at home using their computer and log in to web site and manage files.

Comment: I think you need to run as admin.  You either have to run executable directly from window.  Or create a shortcut to VS.  Then start VS by right click shortcut and select Run as Admin.

Comment: I did however i am getting same error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: Try using cmd.exe > Set  and check environmental variable userdomain and userdnsdomain.  Do they match your query?  Did you need \\\\ before your paths.